# VBA copy sheet to multiple workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the below code to copy a sheet in a master file to multiple excel files in the same folder,

```
Sub Copy_Sheet_to_new_workbooks()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String

MyFolder = "G:\Corpdata\Community Division\Team\Divisional BAU\21. Serious Incidents from June 2021\Data analysis\All_Data"

MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")

Do While MyFile <> ""
           
    Workbooks("All_Data.xlsk").Sheets("Table2").Copy After:=Workbooks(MyFile).Sheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

MyFile = Dir$ 'goes to next entry
Loop

End Sub
```

However when I run this code I get a subscript out of range error. I have tried many fixes but keep getting the same error message.

Comment: Typo in filename: `"All_Data.xlsk"` - should probably be `xlsx`?

Comment: AFraid that has not fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a Workbook before you use it, eg to copy a sheet into it.

```
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\*.xlsx")
Do While MyFile <> ""
    Dim MyWorkbook as Workbook
    Set MyWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(MyFolder & "\" & MyFile)
    Workbooks("All_Data.xlsx").Sheets("Table2").Copy After:=MyWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    MyWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    MyFile = Dir 'goes to next entry
Loop
```